# How to have multioutput in text classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, text-classification

I'm doing dialect text classification. The problem is some tweets, can be classified as both dialect A and B, how can I do that? I want to do it and then automatically calculate the accuracy, I don't want to do it manually. When I don't classify them as both A and B, it gives me many misclassified texts.

In the training though, they're not classified as both dialect A and B. but separately.

Comment: You need to try different things. One is that you can make a new class in the case where both A and B are possible. So now your data will be a 3-class problem. Or you can try multi-label classification. See this:https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `OneHotEncoding`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Your target will look similar to
target = ['A', 'A', 'B']

# After OneHotEncoding
[[1, 0],
 [1, 0],
 [0, 1]]
```

After training on this target, your model will predict the probability of the class. You can set a threshhold to classify the prediction to both the classes

```
# Sample output
[[1., 0.],
 [0.5, 0.5],
 [0.1, 0.9]]

predictions = ['A', 'A and B', 'B']
```

[Example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/)

Comment: I have some questions: 1) who's going to output 'A and B'? is it me, or the naive bayes classifier(i'm using naive bayes)? 2) Is it possible to use accuracy_score from scikit learn automatically? because there're no labels as 'A and B' in my training set. So do you think I can calculate the accuracy automatically? 3) Do I have to visit every label and check if it's either A or B, and then calculate the difference between their probabilities and based on that I make the output? isn't there a more automated way?

Comment: 1) Output `'A and B'` will be done manually after calculating the threshold. As you are using `Naive Bayes` classifier in `scikit-learn`, have a look at the [`predict_prob()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.predict_proba) method, it returns the class probabilily, so you don't have to use `OneHotEncoder`

Comment: 2) `accuracy_score` cannot be used directly as the combined class is absent from the dataset. 3) Yes! - If by "manually" you mean running a loop to calculate the output after thresh-holding